# OSX El Capitan Permanently change PHP version

Tags: php, macos, osx-elcapitan, php-7

I have installed PHP 7.0 from here http://php-osx.liip.ch/ and followed instructions to add the new php to my `$PATH` but in a new terminal window `php -v` still shows the old default version.

The new version is used if I `source .profile` or `source .bash_profile` (tried both)

I have even added the new PHP path to my `.bashrc` but still no luck.

How can I get my mac to always use the new version of PHP by default?

Note:
Symink not an option as I'm on El Capitan.

**~/.bashrc**:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: especially with el-capitan, use **[brew](http://brew.sh)**  to install anything on your mac ... it knows the intricacies of the ever growing layer of osx garbage being thrown on top of an otherwise perfectly fine *nix box.  I just looked, php71 seems quite complete at the moment.

Comment: did you really mean php5 on your path ?

Comment: Just looking at brew now...

@YvesLeBorg yes that is where 7.0 gets installed by default which I confirmed by running `/usr/local/php5/bin/php -v`

Comment: +1 on brew.  It also makes it easy to run multiple versions of PHP and switch between them.  I have sites I manage on 5.6 and 7 in production, so I like to have the correct version running in development for the current project.

Comment: @rosscooper two things : urghhh ... nasty about the path confusion. It will get to be mayhem when you later install extensions and/or maybe apache.  Also, make certain the last line of your .bash_profile looks like `[ -r ~/.bashrc ] && source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `~/.bash_profile` instead of  `~/.bashrc` file on Mac.

If `source ~/.bash_profile` can solve the problem, that means the file is not sourced when you open a new terminal. If you are using `zsh`, you should add `source ~/.bash_profile` to your `~/.zshrc` file.

However, `brew` is a better option.

Comment: am using zsh so that could be the issue, I am currently installing via `brew` to see how it goes

Comment: No wonder. I'm using zsh, and couldn't figure out why it would never work with `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`. Editing `~/.zshrc` did the trick~